# How to enable AWS-SNS raw message delivery in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to enable raw message delivery when subscribing in java

what param can i set ?

```
AmazonSNSClient amazonSNSClient = (AmazonSNSClient) AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
    SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest();
    SubscribeResult subscribeResult = new SubscribeResult();
    subscribeRequest.setTopicArn(createTopicResult.getTopicArn());
    subscribeRequest.setProtocol(protocol);
    subscribeRequest.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    subscribeResult = amazonSNSClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `withAttribute` and pass in `RawMessageDelivery`. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/model/SubscribeRequest.html#withAttributes-java.util.Map-).